# How to make my app receive location intents like Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

If you opened a link like [this](https://www.google.com/maps/place/El-Andalus,+El-Bagour+City,+El-Bagour,+Menofia+Governorate,+Egypt/@30.439627,31.0337001,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x145879a026d5ca57:0x63374cce0692c628!8m2!3d30.439627!4d31.0358888?hl=en)  on your android phone Google maps will automatically open and show you the location on it's map.

I want to make my app receive intents if the user opened a link like this and also i want to get the lat,long from that link.
Is this Possible ?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38115729/making-own-android-app-default-for-map-intents/38117854#38117854

Comment: This really what I wanted,thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the link is stored as String variable ***link***

Now,

```
String[] split_link = link.split(Pattern.quote("@"));
String[] post_link = split_link[1].split(Pattern.quote(","));

double lattitude = Double.parseDouble(post_link[0]);
double longitude = Double.parseDouble(post_link[1]);
```

Try This!!

Comment: great this would make me get the coordinates , how can i make my app open if someone clicked on a google map location link ?

Comment: Did You mean that the device should open up your Android App when clicked on the link? Please Elaborate your Question!

Comment: Exactly that's what i want beside tbe part you answered too